# Unable to Scrape the threads using rvest in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I need to scrape the threads and replies from the following website:

https://forums.vwvortex.com/forumdisplay.php?5449-Atlas-SUV/page2&pp=200&sort=lastpost&order=desc&daysprune=-1

I tried this code:

```
url<-"https://forums.vwvortex.com/forumdisplay.php?5449-Atlas-SUV/page1&pp=200&sort=lastpost&order=desc&daysprune=-1"

N_pages <- 5    
A <- NULL    
D <- NULL    

for (j in 1: N_pages){    
review <- read_html(paste0(url, j))      
threads<- cbind(review %>% html_nodes(".threadtitle") %>%     html_text()     )    
author <- cbind(review %>% html_nodes(".label") %>%     html_text() )    
X<- rbind(A, threads, author)

x <- as.data.frame(X)
}
```

Problem: I used selectorgadget to get the correct HTML source. However, when I run the code, I do not get the required results.

Output I get:

```
 V1

1 Title/thread Starter

2 Sticky: ****Please use the search****

3 Sticky: **** The Official Atlas SUV DIY/FAQ thread****
```

Required output:

```
Threads   Author    Replies

Text    name, date  text

Text    name, date  text

Text    name, date  text
```

How do to get scrape these threads. Should I use rvest or is it through API/Json? I do I know how to go about it ?

Comment: can you edit and manage the code little bit?

Comment: The code what I have works but does not give me the required results. I tried to first scrape just the threads and the author and date. It scraped something else. Any idea as to whats going wrong in my code or HTML ?

Comment: The problem is in `review <- read_html(paste0(url, j))`. What is that you are trying to achieve using the code
The iteration of the URLS will be as follows
`https://forums.vwvortex.com/forumdisplay.php?5449-Atlas-SUV/page2&pp=200&sort=lastpost&order=desc&daysprune=-11`

`https://forums.vwvortex.com/forumdisplay.php?5449-Atlas-SUV/page2&pp=200&sort=lastpost&order=desc&daysprune=-12`

And if you go to the above URL's you will see only Sticky: ***Please use the search***

Comment: @Bharath Thank you so much. Is there a way I can scrape the threads along with the replies? I cant find the HTML node for each thread’s replies.

Comment: @gamyanaidu so you want both the titles and the individual replies inside each topic?

Comment: @Bharath Yes I need the title , threads , and its individual replies

Comment: Is there a different way to look for the replies' HTML node ?